# `Access Denied` for some files, when syncing buckets

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I'm using `awscli` to sync 2 buckets (same account):

```
aws s3 sync --only-show-errors s3://bucket-1 s3://bucket-2
```

but for some files I get permission errors:

```
copy failed: s3://bucket-1/dirname/file.flac to s3://bucket-2/dirname/file.flac An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the UploadPartCopy operation: Access Denied
```

(in some cases the the failing operation is `CopyObject`)

this only seems to happen for `.flac` files. all other files are `.mp3`s, so the only difference is I can think of is the file size.

---

since I'm using a user with full s3 permissions for this, I don't understand why this is happening (or how this could be fixed).

Comment: did you get your problem answered? If yes please accept one of the answers to reward the responders for the time they spent answering you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the *object* is owned by a different account?

It may happen when a bucket in AWS account AAA is writable by AWS account BBB, e.g. through *BucketPolicy*, but the writer (in BBB) didn't specify `--acl bucket-owner-full-control` permission when uploading it.

Check the object's ACL using:

```
aws s3api get-object-acl --bucket bucket-1 --key dirname/file.flac
```

Similar for the destination - if an existing object is owned by a different account you won't be able to overwrite it. That's why `UploadPartCopy` would fail.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

for me it failed because UploadPartCopy operation require additional permissions then regular copy, I changed policy to s3:List* and it worked.